# Simplify this PHP?

Tags: php

I was copy/pasting some PHP to get the outcome I wanted but I believe this could be simplified in a much better way. Could any developers help a designer out?

```
<?php
$url = dirname(__FILE__);
$id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1 );
echo '<img src="../i/';
echo $id;
echo '.png" alt="';
echo $id;
echo '" />'; 
?>
```

**Result:**     `<img src="(name of $id)" alt="(name of $id)" />`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PHP's string interpolation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for that:

```
echo "<img src=\"../i/$id.png\" alt=\"$id\" />";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="../i/<?php echo $id; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $id ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = dirname(__FILE__);
$id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1 );
echo "<img src=\"../i/$id.png\" alt=\"$id\" />"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recycleable version:

```
function img_tag () {
  $url = dirname(__FILE__);
  $id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1 );
  return "<img src=\"../i/$id.png\" alt=\"$id\" />";
}
```

elsewhere in your document, call this function as follows:

```
<?php echo img_tag(); ?>
```

Comment: You need to escape the inner `"`s.

Comment: Is that... a 3D smiley with his nose jutting out? You just blew my mind.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<?php
$url = dirname(__FILE__);
$id = substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' )+1 ); ?>

<img src="../i/<?php echo $id >.png" alt="<?php echo $id >" />
```